# VSCode "auto save" or "save" is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed the VSCode!

My VSCode does not save files in any format.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you think it will not safe like a img that saves as a .jpg or .png it does your html will save itself as a example.html an php will safe itself as a example.php